# Display a tooltip onmouseover in Inkscape-generated image

Tags: pdf, javascript, inkscape, svg

I'd like a tooltip with some text to be displayed when mouse is over some graphical element in a media I create with Inkscape, ideally a PDF, but I could use an SVG.

I believe this is possible, since Inkscape allows to fill in an `onmouseover` field for `Object properties`. I haven't found a documentation, but I believe it to expect javascript? I tried to enter `tooltip("my message");`, and tried to view with inkview and firefox the resulting SVG, and with okular and evince the exported PDF, but no tooltip appears.

Comment: SVG files can have `onmouseover` attributes. But this has nothing to do with PDF and I don't think that such interactive parts of the SVG spec are translated to PDF exports.

Answer (score 1):

I would love to be able to do something like this too.  My goal is to send emails with images that have clickable links and tooltips.  Unfortunately, the only way that works so far is converting the SVG file into an HTML file and adding it as an attachment to email.  The user has a few extra clicks but it seems to work so far (Just now tried a few experiments with this, so time may reveal problems).

To do this:

1. For a tooltip only on an object, go to object's Object Properties, place tooltip text in "Title:" and don't forget to press the "Set" button.
2. For a link, bring up the context menu on the object and select "Create Link", and in the object's Object attributes enter the link in "Href:" and the tooltip text in "Title:".
3. Create the HTML file with the following content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Inkscape Output</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

4. Save the SVG file that has the tooltips or links you created, then open it in a text editor such as notepad, copy the entire file, paste it into the body section of the HTML file created in the above step, and save the now modified HTML file.
5. Create an email and attach the new HTML file.

If anyone finds a better way, would love to hear it.